# Error and System.IndexOutOfRangeException exception while generating PDF and PDF/A using iTextSharp v5.5.2.0

Tags: c#, itext

I am uisng iTextsharp v5.5.2.0 to generate a large batch of PDF and PDF/A. at the start of the batch things work fine but afterwards I start reveive this kind of error exception.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: L'index se trouve en dehors des limites du  
tableau.
à System.IO.FileStream.ReadByte()
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.ReadInt()
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontSubSet.CreateTableDirectory()
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontSubSet.Process()
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.GetSubSet(HashSet2`1 glyphs, Boolean   
subsetp)
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.TtfUnicodeWriter.WriteFont(TrueTypeFontUnicode font, 
PdfIndirectReference refer, Object[] parms, Byte[] rotbits)
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.WriteFont(PdfWriter writer,  
PdfIndirectReference piref, Object[] parms)
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.FontDetails.WriteFont(PdfWriter writer)
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddSharedObjectsToBody()
à iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
à iTextSharp.text.Document.Close()"
```

The generated files are damaged and could not be opened by Adobe Reader. The font file used to create the baseFont is "ArialUNI.ttf" like this sample

```
BaseFont basefont = BaseFont.CreateFont(FontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,  
BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

I tried replacing the font file but still the same exception happens. Any ideas why we could have such errors. a similar error was mentioned [here](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Problems-when-using-iTextSharp-in-a-multithreaded-application-td4660023.html) but still has no answer.

Comment: This sounds like a bug that was already fixed in a later version. Did you already try a later version?

Comment: Furthermore, please supply enough code to allow reproducing your issue.

Comment: Thank you Bruno, using the latest version of iTextSharp " v5.5.10.0" solved the issue.